Find minimum element plus index between 8 zmm registers
I want to find the first minimal element and its index of a 64 element long array with the avx512 instuction set. The code works and is in the context of a function that is faster than the equivalent written in pure C (I have this code embedded with inline asm in cpp and tested against an equivalent written in pure C), however, the identification of the minindex is a performance weakspot and I feel this could be optimized to perform better. To start we have an 64 double array distributed in the zmm registers 16 to 23, first I find the minimum element by comparing the registers in a tree like fashion, however once we arrive at a single register, I have to shuffle elements around to end up with the min element in the lower 64 bits of xmm0.
Then I compare the minimum element to each original register and save the output in opmask register, which I shift by multiples of 8, since each zmm register contains 8 doubles and xor into k1. Finally I count the leading zeros to get the overall index.
I tried to skip half of the comparisions by first comparing to the intermediate minvalues and then searching for the min element in only the upper or lower half, but even though this leads to less instructions in the worst case, it introduces a branch and the code runs slower than the branchless version.
here is the code:
; first set of comparisions
vminpd %zmm17, %zmm16, %zmm0
vminpd %zmm19, %zmm18, %zmm1
vminpd %zmm21, %zmm20, %zmm2
vminpd %zmm23, %zmm22, %zmm3

; compare min of 16,17 against 18,19 then 20,21 against 22,23
vminpd %zmm1, %zmm0, %zmm0
vminpd %zmm3, %zmm2, %zmm1

vminpd %zmm0, %zmm1, %zmm0


; These are the last 8 comparisions
vextractf64x4 $1, %zmm0, %ymm1
vminpd %ymm1, %ymm0, %ymm0
vextracti128 $1, %ymm0, %xmm1
vminpd %xmm1, %xmm0, %xmm0
movhlps %xmm1, %xmm1
vminpd %xmm1, %xmm0, %xmm0

; broadcast the min value to all of zmm0
vpbroadcastq %xmm0, %zmm0

; Now compare the min value to all of the original registers and get the minindex
vpcmpeqq %zmm16, %zmm0, %k1
vpcmpeqq %zmm17, %zmm0, %k2
kshiftlq $8, %k2, %k2
korq %k1, %k2, %k1
vpcmpeqq %zmm18, %zmm0, %k2
kshiftlq $16, %k2, %k2
korq %k1, %k2, %k1
vpcmpeqq %zmm19, %zmm0, %k2
kshiftlq $24, %k2, %k2
korq %k1, %k2, %k1
vpcmpeqq %zmm20, %zmm0, %k2
kshiftlq $32, %k2, %k2
korq %k1, %k2, %k1
vpcmpeqq %zmm21, %zmm0, %k2
kshiftlq $40, %k2, %k2
korq %k1, %k2, %k1
vpcmpeqq %zmm22, %zmm0, %k2
kshiftlq $48, %k2, %k2
korq %k1, %k2, %k1
vpcmpeqq %zmm23, %zmm0, %k2
kshiftlq $56, %k2, %k2
korq %k1, %k2, %k1

; count the leading zeros
kmovq %k1, %rcx
tzcnt %rcx, %rcx


much faster than the equivalent C code - citation needed. I won't believe it until you show your build flags and your benchmarking code.

Yeah, the registers contain values from previous arithmetic operations that are ~ 30x faster in avx-512 and benchmarked with -march=native and -O2. So the whole whole code is much faster in assembly than in C, but finding the minimum index is currently a performance weak spot and reduces the improvement to only x10 speedup. I should have clarified that better in the text. The pure performance from loading the array from memory into the registers and then finding the minindex might be slower this way. I don't want to post the whole code though, because it is pretty long.


movhlps %xmm1, %xmm1


As far as I know, this is fine in this case (the CPUs that support AVX-512 don't have the slow SSE-AVX-transition but legacy-encoded SSE instructions can have a false dependence on their output .. but not movhlps %xmm1, %xmm1 which has a true dependence on its output anyway). Looks odd among all the (E)VEX-encoded instructions but I think that's all.

vpcmpeqq 


So comparing doubles for bitwise equality. No problem, but I think it's worth a comment in the code.
vpcmpeqq and kshiftlq both execute only on p5 on the Intel Lakes, you can avoid that port contention by doing the mask concatenation in GPRs (so kmovq to a GPR, shift and or there). On the other hand, performance on Zen4 may suffer from that.
Calculating the minimum and then finding its index is not a bad approach. There is an alternative, actually I don't know for sure whether it's better, but you can try it. The alternative is computing the index of every element while computing the minimum: use a regular comparison yielding a mask (instead of vminpd), use that mask both to blend together the vectors of doubles (yielding pairwise minima) and to also blend together vectors of indices (yielding the index of every minimum). Then after a similar tree-wise reduction, you have both the minimum and its index.
